# Do we have an application of StackExchange or (Movies & TV) on Play store, WMP or on Blackberry world?

Tags: discussion, promotion

I tried in the play store, but I didn't get the app. So do we have this app there, and also if we don't have then, can we have this in future. I think it will promote StackExchange.

Comment: This might probably better fit (or find a better answer, if there isn't already one) on the [primary meta](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/).

Comment: @ChristianRau Its already done there thrice i think.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not Official but there are various unofficial apps, one of them is [Stack Remote](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.b5d.android&hl=en) (No product placement intended and its not even preferred by me).

On [main meta](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/), its already been discussed various times [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/182709/is-there-any-official-stack-overflow-android-app), [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/116038/are-there-mobile-apps-for-stack-overflow) and [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/154797/do-stack-overflow-and-other-stack-exchange-sites-have-an-app-i-can-use) and might be somewhere else but no official app made yet. There is only a mobile version of the SE site's.

**Update:** Finally we have an [Android App](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/?cb=1).

Answer (score 1):

The official Stack Overflow Android app is now in open Beta testing. Details are at:

[Stack Exchange Android app in beta](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/215992/stack-exchange-android-app-in-beta)

Blog announcement: [Stack Exchange for Android is here!](http://blog.stackoverflow.com/2014/01/stack-exchange-for-android-is-here/)

Comment: Thanx for the insight

Answer (score 1):

Coming in and hijacking this old question to state that there is now an official StackExchange app for

[**Google Play**](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=com.stackexchange.marvin)

[**iOS**](https://itunes.apple.com/us/app/stack-exchange/id871299723?mt=8)

Answer (score 0):

We are one of many many Stack Exchange sites.

As @ChristianRau says - this might be better asked on [meta.stackoverflow.com](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/) - which is the meta site for the entire StackExchange network.   Check there next, there may be already questions on here about this.

That said, I do not believe there is an official mobile client for any platform, iOS, Android or Blackberry.  I have however come across third party apps for Stackoverflow.